# Using Testng to write unit test for spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, testng

I am using testng to write unit tests for my application which is based on spring boot. For using testng, i have first added its dependency in pom.xml and also installed its plugin from eclipse marketplace.

The problem is, when i run a test class using testng test, i am getting a null pointer exception but the test class seems to be correct.

In this location i am getting the error

```
Mockito.when(offerRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(ol);
```

Comment: share your test class to figure out more!

Comment: also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask a question, this way you can improve our understanding and this way get better help